# rails- display certian number of characters from a textfield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text

I running a rails project and I am displaying a textfield that can often be too long.  If there any things I can call to only display 20 words or 120 characters on the the view page ??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may be interested in TextHelper's [truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001743) function:

```
  truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away")
  # => Once upon a time in a world f...

  truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", :length => 14)
  # => Once upon a...

  truncate("And they found that many people were sleeping better.", :length => 25, "(clipped)")
  # => And they found that many (clipped)

  truncate("And they found that many people were sleeping better.", :omission => "... (continued)", :length => 15)
  # => And they found... (continued)
```

Comment: In ruby you can also just give a range to a string. mystring[0..119]

Answer (score 4):

```
'Once upon a time in a world far far away'.truncate(27)
"Once upon a time in a wo..."

'Once upon a time in a world far far away'.truncate(27, separator: ' ')
"Once upon a time in a..."

'Once upon a time in a world far far away'.truncate(27, separator: /\s/)
"Once upon a time in a..."

'And they found that many people were sleeping better.'.truncate(25, omission: '... (continued)')
"And they f... (continued)"
```

You can see this example too

[truncate](http://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate)